# How to add max size of 20 to stack by linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I have implemented a stack by linked list as you can see below, but I can't get a max size to work. I want the stack to hold a maximum of 20 items and also display when the stack is full.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
int data;
Node *link;
};

Node *top = NULL;

bool isempty()
{
 if(top == NULL)
 return true; else
 return false;
}

void push (int value)
{
  Node *ptr = new Node();
  ptr->data = value;
  ptr->link = top;
  top = ptr;
}

void pop ( )
{
 if ( isempty() )
  cout<<"Stack is Empty";
 else
 {
  cout << "pop element" << endl;
  Node *ptr = top;
  top = top -> link;
  delete(ptr);
 }
}

void showTop()
{
 if ( isempty() )
  cout<<"Stack is Empty";
 else
  cout<<"Element at top is : "<< top->data << endl;
}

void displayStack()
{
  //print stack
 if ( isempty() )
  cout<<"Stack is Empty" << endl;
 else
 {
  cout << "Stack: " << endl;
  Node *temp=top;
  while(temp!=NULL)
  {   cout<<temp->data<<" ";
   temp=temp->link;
  }
  cout<<"\n";
 }
 }
```

I would like to have a function like my isEmpty() but isFull() to display the stack is full when 20 items are in the stack. I have not included my main function in the above snippet as I just call my functions.

Thanks for all suggestions much appreciated :) I'm fairly knew to c++ so take it easy.

Comment: If you want a maximum of 20 objects, why use a linked list? An array would suffice. Part of the benefits of a linked list is that there is no maximum (except for the total memory your program can use, of course).

Comment: How are you going to keep count of the number of items?  Somehow, by some means (maybe create a class, rearrange code, etc.), you have to stick a counter somewhere -- maybe figuring that out was part of the assignment.  As to the code -- you're showing code that totally misses how to track this information.  As a matter of fact, this is mostly a question of design, not details on what `pop()` or `displayStack()` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want to wrap things up in a class that has a size variable.

```
struct Stack
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node * link;
    };

    Node * top = NULL;
    size_t size = 0U;

    void push(int val)
    {
        // stuff you already have
        ++size;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        // stuff you already have
        --size;
    }

    // other methods you have
};
```

Node doesn't know about how many are in the list, so you need to use Node as a building block, not the structure itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I would use some sort of struct with a pointer to the head node and a value to capture the maximum size of the stack. When you push onto the stack you need to increment that value and check to ensure it has not exceeded the maximum stack size prior to pushing. Also, peek is usually the accepted function name for showTop().